# How to prevent Eclipse form opening a specific view which opened last time

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My plug-in for Eclipse 4.0+ has a `MyView`,

```
Class MyView extends ViewPart{}
```

If I do the following steps:

1. open Eclipse and open `MyView`
2. close Eclipse
3. start up Eclipse again

then 
Does anyone know how to stop Eclipse from opening `Myview` when I start up Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

In your `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point declaring the view specify `false` for the `restorable` attribute.

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views"> 
  <view 
     restorable="false"
     id="com.xyz.views.XYZView" 
     name="XYZ View" 
     class="com.xyz.views.XYZView" 
     icon="icons/XYZ.png"/>
</extension>
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? There have been several bugs reported against this for Eclipse 4 but they are all marked as fixed.

Comment: I did try what you said, but your answer doesn't work for my question in eclipse 4

Comment: Please confirm that this is a 3.x compatibilty mode view using the `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point rather than an e4 part in the Application.e4xmi (which wouldn't use ViewPart).

Comment: You may also have to start Eclipse with `-clean` to get it to pick up the changes to the view definition.

Comment: i use org.eclipse.ui.views

Comment: may you tell me the way  start Eclipse with, i'm not sure i did right ,i place -clean in program arguments text  for  Eclipse Application run configrations ,thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, -clean goes in the program arguments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131637/discussion-between-star-and-greg-449).